# Post request using nodejs doesn't get inside $_GET

Tags: php, node.js

First, the PHP script:

```
error_log("inside the script"); //this is logged

if(isset($_GET['test'])){
    echo "test";
    echo json_encode("test");
}
```

And the nodejs bit

```
var postToPHP = function(data, path, method_type){

var querystring = require("querystring");
data = querystring.stringify(data);

console.log("stringified data:",data);

var options = {
    host : 'localhost',
    path : path,
    method : method_type,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length' : data.length
    }
};

var buffer = "";

var http_client = require('http');
var reqPost = http_client.request(options, function(res) {

    res.on('data', function(d) {
            buffer = buffer+d;
        });
    res.on('end', function() {
           console.log("buffer",buffer);
         });

reqPost.write(data);
reqPost.end();
}

postToPHP("test","/test.php","GET");
postToPHP({"test":"null"},"/test.php","GET");
```

I can't really understand why this happens because I actually had it working before. Then I changed something I can't understand what and it stopped working... any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the query parameter parsed into $_GET too!

```
postToPHP("test","/test.php?test=1","GET");
postToPHP({"test":"null"},"/test.php?test=1","GET");
```

Comment: That did work alright! But can you tell me how can I fix my function for it to work dinamically? I'm pretty sure there must be a way for this schema to work...